# How I can change the GDM login screen wallpaper?

Tags: boot, login, gdm, desktop-background

How I can change the GDM 3.6 Wallpaper? I dont mean the desktop background, but the Wallpaper at the login (GDM 3.6).

Thanks

---

Thank you for your answer,

I know exactly what you mean. Recently I had installed LightDm, but today I uninstalled it, and replaced it with GDM. Ubuntu-Tweak dont show the login screen appearance button. I think it's because LightDM is currently not installed.
Does anyone know where is the folder where the images are stored?

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate, but I just spent 10 minutes searching and nothing... +1 then, hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the purple background color of the lock screen on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981614/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-the-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 8):

Also worth mentioning with Ubuntu Artful `17.10`, you can revert to the default Gnome 3 theme experience with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

And selecting the default `gnome-shell.css` option.

Source: https://didrocks.fr/2017/09/11/ubuntu-gnome-shell-in-artful-day-11/

###### Other Ubuntu and Debian Versions

The `alternatives`  system in Debian and Ubuntu relies on "link group" names to configure software or files with similar functionality.  A generic name in the `/etc/alternatives/` filesystem is shared by all files included within different software packages providing interchangeable functionality.

Note that this "link group" name may be different, even for the same piece of software, depending on which version of Ubuntu or Debian you are working on. To see the available link groups on your system, run:

```bash
update-alternatives --get-selections
```

For this particular example with `gdm3`, you might want to filter this to only the `gdm`-related names:

```bash
update-alternatives --get-selections`  | grep -i gdm

# Returns the following on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
# gdm3-theme.gresource           auto     /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

To configure this link group name, just pass it along to `update-alternatives --config $LINK_GROUP_NAME_HERE` (e.g.):

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource
```

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --auto gdm3.css` gives me `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3.css`

Comment: @Bram: The "link group" name may be different, depending on which version of Ubuntu you are working on.  To see the available gdm-related link groups on your system, run: `update-alternatives --get-selections  | grep -i gdm`

Comment: @Bram: Updated this answer with more generic version-agnostic instructions for finding the appropriate "link group" name.

Answer (score 6):

1. Copy the image you want to use into the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` folder

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
   ```
2. Search for the following section

   ```
   #lockDialogGroup {
   background: #2e3436 url(noise-texture.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   ```
3. Change the name of the image to your image
4. Set *background* to *repeat* or *no-repeat*
5. Save the file

Logout and your new background is there

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instructions on the Arch Linux Wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image

Here is what you need to do:

### 1. Extract the gnome-shell-theme bianry

Create and run the following script (**`/usr/local/bin/extractgst.sh`**)

```bash
#!/bin/sh

workdir=${HOME}/shell-theme
if [ ! -d ${workdir}/theme ]; then
  mkdir -p ${workdir}/theme
fi
gst=/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource

for r in `gresource list $gst`; do
        gresource extract $gst $r >$workdir/${r#\/org\/gnome\/shell/}
done
```

### 2. Edit gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml and gnome-shell.css (section `#lockDialogGroup`)

This creates the directory `$HOME/shell-theme/theme`. Change directory to this location.

Then create the file **`gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml`** in the directory above.

With the following content, while ***imagefilename*** must be replaced with the filename of your **background image**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/shell/theme">

    <file>imagefilename</file>

    <file>calendar-arrow-left.svg</file>
    <file>calendar-arrow-right.svg</file>
    <file>calendar-today.svg</file>
    <file>checkbox-focused.svg</file>
    <file>checkbox-off-focused.svg</file>
    <file>checkbox-off.svg</file>
    <file>checkbox.svg</file>
    <file>close-window.svg</file>
    <file>close.svg</file>
    <file>corner-ripple-ltr.png</file>
    <file>corner-ripple-rtl.png</file>
    <file>dash-placeholder.svg</file>
    <file>filter-selected-ltr.svg</file>
    <file>filter-selected-rtl.svg</file>
    <file>gnome-shell.css</file>
    <file>gnome-shell-high-contrast.css</file>
    <file>logged-in-indicator.svg</file>
    <file>more-results.svg</file>
    <file>no-events.svg</file>
    <file>no-notifications.svg</file>
    <file>noise-texture.png</file>
    <file>page-indicator-active.svg</file>
    <file>page-indicator-inactive.svg</file>
    <file>page-indicator-checked.svg</file>
    <file>page-indicator-hover.svg</file>
    <file>process-working.svg</file>
    <file>running-indicator.svg</file>
    <file>source-button-border.svg</file>
    <file>summary-counter.svg</file>
    <file>toggle-off-us.svg</file>
    <file>toggle-off-intl.svg</file>
    <file>toggle-on-hc.svg</file>
    <file>toggle-on-us.svg</file>
    <file>toggle-on-intl.svg</file>
    <file>ws-switch-arrow-up.png</file>
    <file>ws-switch-arrow-down.png</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Now, open the *`gnome-shell.css`*-file in the directory and change the #lockDialogGroup definition as follows:

```css
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2e3436 url(imagefilename);
  background-size: [WIDTH]px [HEIGHT]px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Set `background-size` to the resolution that GDM uses, this might not necessarily be the resolution of the image.

### 3. Then again compile it

Finally, compile the theme using the following command:

```
glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
```

### 4. Copy the compiled gnome-shell-theme file

And copy the resulting `gnome-shell-theme.gresource`-file to the `/usr/share/gnome-shell` directory.

### 5. Restart gdm or logout

Eventually restart gdm or just logout.

### Finished!

Comment: I agree and automated this solution here: https://gitlab.com/zachbryant/Bash-Scripts/raw/master/GDM%20Custom%20Bg/chgdm-bg.sh

Comment: @Zach Why don't you post your script as an answer within this question? Ping me and I'll upvote it... You'll go from 3 points to 13 at least!

Comment: Jesus Christ! If it’s so hard to change, no wonder The Year of The Linux Desktop will never come (!!)

Answer (score 4):

I created a script which does this with just a few clicks.

You can download it at https://github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-change-login-background

But before you download, you will need to install yad package for graphical interface. In Ubuntu, you just install it with `sudo apt install yad`.

After that, you just run `sudo ./ubuntu-change-login-background` and a window show up for you to choose your favorite image with previews.

When you select your background image, you will see a popup message saying `Login image successfully changed`. After that, you simply type y or Y to restart your gnome-session and apply the change.

---

You can see the result below with the beautiful Flat-Remix Gnome theme.

[image: My GDM Screen]

It was never so simple.

Comment: Worked like a charm on 20.04, read the links on the download page!

Comment: good job, it works perfectly!   For **Ubuntu 20.04 and pop OS 20.04 users:** download is [here](https://github.com/thiggy01/change-gdm-background) and the procedure is: 1) Install dependency: `sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin`   2) Download the script: `wget github.com/thiggy01/change-gdm-background/raw/master/change-gdm-background` 3) Make it executable `chmod +x /PATH/TO/change-gdm-background` 4) Set bg image with `sudo ./change-gdm-background /PATH/TO/IMAGE` or set a bg color with `sudo ./change-gdm-background \#yourhexcode`.

Comment: This was the only solution I got to work on `Pop_OS! Hirsuite Hippo`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ `which gsettings` \
  set com.ubuntu.login-screen background-picture-uri /path/to/greeter.jpg
```

You will need to match the screen size. i.e if you have 2 2k screens the image needs to be 5120x1440.

You can also set color, which will also fill around image if it's not covering the whole screen.

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ `which gsettings` \
  set com.ubuntu.login-screen background-color '#9c0031'
```

There are 2 other keys `background-repeat` which I assume takes the corresponding [css values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp), haven't checked.
And `background-size` that takes:

- auto - original image size
- cover - scale to cover and crop extra
- contain - stretch to fit

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Does not need any other dependencies or installs. Thank you @Tamir

Answer (score 1):

You will need Ubuntu Tweak, if you do not have it already you can install it by running the following codes in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then launch Ubuntu Tweak and search for "login" in the search bar then click on "login settings" then press the unlock button in the top right by the search bar. Then you can edit your login screen as you choose by changing the background or Icon theme ect.

[image]

This should work for both GDM login as well as LightDM.

Source: http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/01/how-to-change-gdmlogin-screen.html

Comment: This does not work for GDM(3).

Comment: Looked promising, but not working for me on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: trying this instead https://github.com/Nano77/various/tree/master/deb

Answer (score 1):

How to change Gnome 3 lock screen background:

- GDM Background Grey is loacated in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/noise-texture.png`

  - Rename `noise-texture.png` as `noise-texture.png.bak` (as root)
  - Copy a background of your choice in the above folder and rename it as `noise-texture.png` (as root)
  - Restart gnome-shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>R</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(Every update to gnome-shell will replace your noise-texture.png with the original, so you have keep repeating the above after every gnome-shell upgrade)

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189983&p=12857494#post12857494)

Answer (score 0):

I just went exploring. Check out `/etc/gdm/greeter.gsettings`

In the terminal, you can get READ access to this file by typing:

```
nano /etc/gdm/greeter.gsettings
```

You'll see in that file a reference to: `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds`
which appears to hold the stripe backgrounds you're looking for. Good luck!

Remember, you'll need to elevate using `sudo` to write to this directory. Or if you would rather use the graphical interface, you can type this in the terminal to open up `gedit` as an elevated user, but be careful not to wreck your system:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/gdm/greeter.gsettings
```

Comment: nope, didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I use [gdm-tools](https://github.com/realmazharhussain/gdm-tools):

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev dconf-cli
git clone --depth=1 --single-branch https://github.com/realmazharhussain/gdm-tools.git
cd gdm-tools
./install.sh
set-gdm-theme -s default ~/Pictures/gdm_wallpaper.png
```

Answer (score 0):

### Keep Calm and Use an App:

**Login Manager Settings:** https://flathub.org/apps/io.github.realmazharhussain.GdmSettings