# Ubuntu 18.04, vanilla GNOME: Force lock screen background to be the same as GDM background?

Tags: gnome, login, gdm

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and vanilla GNOME desktop, things mostly work as expected - except for the purple background set in the GNOME lock screen. "Default" GNOME behaviour apparently is to have the same background in GDM login and lock screen which is just what I want (that default strange greyish texture).

Is there a "good" (upgrade-surviving) way of changing this? I read through

[How can I change the purple background color of the lock screen on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981614/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-the-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-17-10)

which is closest to what I want, but from one point I don't want to set an arbitrary background for the lock screen (and failed to figure out what background image / configuration is used in GDM login), and messing with gdm3.css didn't change anything. Any input on that greatly appreciated.

Comment: My 18.04 lock screen is set using Nautilus script but I have the Unity desktop and haven't tried with GNOME desktop yet: https://askubuntu.com/questions/871312/nautilus-can-set-desktop-wallpaper-how-can-it-set-login-and-lock-screen-wallpap

Comment: @KristianRink are you using `GNOME on Xorg` desktop session? how did you install this session? `sudo apt install gnome-session` or `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop` ??

Comment: @KristianRink i am trying to solve this, when i installed it in both the ways the unlock-screen is the greyish one.. did you find any solution in your case?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNt5t.jpg are you using which option? observe which session are you in when the purple background is on unlock-screen?