# How can I access /org/gnome/shell/theme/ which is referred to in the ubuntu.css file on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell

Is there a way to access `///org/gnome/shell/theme/` in Ubuntu 18.04?
I got this path in a `.css` file from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`,

for example:

```
resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg  
resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-on-us.svg
```

Example:

```
.check-box StBin {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg"); }


.check-box:checked StBin {
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox.svg"); }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not looking for [`dconf-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf-editor.1.html)?

Comment: @AlexP No, `/org/gnome/shell/theme/` is not accessible using `dconf-editor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/org/gnome/shell/theme/` is *not* an actual directory that you can access (you **cannot** access it *using dconf Editor either*). This is associated to the GResource mechanism, GNOME shell can get the resource from the `resource://` URI. Generally they're not human-readable as they are pre-compiled into a binary format.

You can however extract the the resource using the `gresource` command. You should be able to find a `.gresource` file somewhere in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/` directory for shell theme. First check whether it contains the resource you're looking for by running

```
gresource list /path/to/filename.gresource | grep <resource-name>
```

for example,

```
gresource list /path/to/filename.gresource | grep checkbox-off.svg
```

Once confirmed, run the following command to extract the resource

```
gresource extract /path/to/filename.gresource /path/to/resource
```

for example,

```
gresource extract /path/to/filename.gresource /org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg
```

It should show you the content of the `.svg` file.

You can use this resource without extracting in the `.css` file for your custom theme as follows

```
url("resource:///path/to/resource");
```

for example,

```
url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg");
```