# Cannot change login screen background in 18.10

Tags: 18.10, login-screen, gdm, desktop-background

I changed both the desktop and login screen background photos. However,only desktop photo is changed. The one on the login screen is still the purple Ubuntu one. Is this a bug?

Comment: Setting->background. What is the difference between lock and lock-in screen? When you lock the computer, you need to go to login screen to enter the password. Shouldn’t they be th same?

Comment: Screen resolution is 4K. Do I need to change something from your provided solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the purple background color of the lock screen on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981614/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-the-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

to change the login screen background in Ubuntu 18.10 with default Display Manager that is gdm3

we need to edit the gdm3.css file.

open the file with your favorite editor, mine is gedit. so
`sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`

go to line number around 1981 and find the below content.

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: none;
  background-color: none;
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: #6D2169;
  background-gradient-end: #370026; }
```

change the content with

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #000000 url(file:///home/pratap/Desktop/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
```

here in the line number 1982 url(file://put your actual image path)

save the file, close & reboot to see the change.

Picture of Lock Screen Wallpaper
[image]

Picture of  Unlock Screen Background
[image]

for 18.04 same method, only line number varies 1814,

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

replace the above content with

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #000000 url(file:///home/pratap/Desktop/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
```

here in the line number 1815 url(file://put your actual image path)

---

Comment: Looks great. Could you update answer to specify if 18.04 works same way too?

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Just curious. Why "file:///" rather than "file://" ?

Comment: This seems like an awfully convoluted way to change a login screen image. Are you _sure_ a more "user-friendly" alternative is not available?

Comment: @PRATAP I'd like to change my login screen to the same solid color that I've got set for my lock screen (in the Background settings panel). Where are the solid color panels located? Is the an easy modification to your answer to do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: @PRATAP Excellent, thanks! However, can you put up the code blocks for 18.10, as you're showing the method for 18.04. Also, wouldn't your `sudo gedit` command be safer with `sudo -H gedit`?

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks for BOTH answers. Whenever opening GRAPHIC apps from the terminal with sudo, `sudo -H` prevents the user's `.ICEauthority` and `.Xauthority` files from getting changed to root:root, and causing a login loop. See `man sudo` for a more terse description.

Comment: Its zoomed in, can you suggest a css tweak to make the image fit to screen

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp @ArunJoshla

Comment: @ArunJoshla its better to have the background pictures same as your screen resolution or at-least the ratio same as width n height

Comment: The first line of /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css is
/* This stylesheet is generated, DO NOT EDIT */
so it doesn't seem like a good idea to edit it. It could revert to the previous value at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a script which automates this process of changing the login background of Gnome Display Manager (gdm).

You just need to type the script name and the image you want. You can even restore a backup of your original theme.

You can find instructions in https://github.com/thiggy01/gdm-change-login-background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Loginized utility for Gnome.
https://github.com/juhaku/loginized

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/926325)

Comment: @mature Looks fine to me. This is *not* a link-only answer, rather it just suggests using an application to achieve the goal and provides a link to that application. Link-only answers are answers which, instead of trying to answer the question, contain only (or mostly) link(s) to (external) site(s) which may have an answer to the question.