# Change login screen purple background 18.10

Tags: login-screen, 18.10

This is almost a dup of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086962/cannot-change-login-screen-background-in-18-10), but with a slight variation.

Instead of using a picture file for the login screen background, I'd like to use the same solid color background that I've set for the lock screen in the **Background** settings panel.

Where are the lock screen solid color panels located? What mod to the referenced question would I need to make? Could I just place a renamed copy of the solid color panel where the current background file is, so that I don't have to modify the gdm3.css file?

I'm looking for the easiest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to change the login screen color equivalent to those 15 colors which are available when we open Settings>Background>LockScreen>color

[image]

first set the required color as lockscreen from the settings>background>lockscreen>color

to know the value of this color run the below command.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver primary-color
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver primary-color
'#7a8aa2'
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

Copy the color, in above case it is `#7a8aa2`

now we need to edit the gdm3.css file.

open the file with your favorite editor, mine is gedit. so
`sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`

go to line number around 1985 & 1986 and find the below content.

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: none;
  background-color: none;
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: #6D2169;
  background-gradient-end: #370026; }
```

change the content with

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: none;
  background-color: none;
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: #7a8aa2;
  background-gradient-end: #7a8aa2; }
```

here in the line number 1985 & 1986 put the color you want in place of #7a8aa2

save the file, close & reboot to see the change.

[image]

[image]

these are the 15 colors + default one.

```
#7a634b
#425265
#475b52
#888888
#7a8aa2
#ff89a9
#ed9116
#d272c4
#437740
#fad166
#ab2876
#5d479d
#008094
#db5d33
#000000

#023c88
```

---

Comment: Excellent! Same color I choose too! Thanks again. I wish they'd drop that purple theme...

Comment: Your/my choice of blue looks a lot more modern than purple :-)

Comment: Just a minor tweak for you... instead of `sudo gedit` you should probably change that to `sudo -H gedit`, so as you don't accidentally create a login loop. Use `sudo -H` whenever you start a graphic app from the command line. Cheers!

Comment: What about changing the date and time appears? @heynnema

Comment: @akikara I don't understand your question.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10 based on locale settings date is displayed as Friday, Jan 25. I want to add year to this.

Comment: How to do this in 19.04? `#lockDialogGroup` is different in `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`, and modifying the background color there doesn't work. If you'd like me to start a new question for this, please let me know :-)

Comment: no, there is already a asked and accepted question relates with 19.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1135698/739431

Comment: please have a look on comments in this post.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1149123/739431 @heynnema

Comment: @PRATAP thanks for the fast reply. My .css file looks different. I tried to modify the color to #7A8AA2 (maybe I should have left lower case a's? Like #7a8aa2), but when I tried it, it just gave a flashing screen. My .css has `#lockDialogGroup {
  background-color: #2C001E; }`.

Comment: @PRATAP Maybe my problem is how I modified the .css file. I had changed `#lockDialogGroup { background-color: #2C001E; }` to `#lockDialogGroup { background-color: #7A8AA2;} ##2C001E; }`. Maybe I forgot the trailing `;` I wonder if that's it, or if it didn't like that I made the last line a comment (so I knew what to go back to if I needed to...).

Comment: @PRATAP yes... that was it. I had an edit error. It's working now.