# Ubuntu 19.04 Can't change LockScreen Background

Tags: gnome-shell, lock-screen

I installed the new version on my new computer and I want to change the lockscreen background I have done this before in the 18.04 LTS version by modifying the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file but on this new version it has changed to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` and I modified the `#lockDialogGroup` selector from this:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
    background: #2e3436 url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
```

to this:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
    background-image: url(file:///home/mauriciogtz/Pictures/Wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;;
    background-position: center; }
```

but I can't get it to work and I have already restarted my computer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in Ubuntu 19.04

the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` will do what you are looking for.

[image]

[image]

---

***Edit on 10th Jan 2020***

you may also have a detailed look on this page https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/login-lock-screen-bg-change for setting the backgrounds via script for Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 & 19.10

Answer (score 2):

You can change lockscreen wallpaper by Settings
[image]

Comment: He meant unlock screen, where you put your password

Answer (score 2):

Some notes about the tip. In my case, Ubuntu 19.04 on May 22, I need to use quotations on file name image.
The image below is on the same folder than `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` file.

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background-image: url("ironman_login_wallpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;;
  background-position: center; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the file `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` also.

[image]