# Lockscreen background not showing after booting

Tags: lock-screen, desktop-background

I have a weird problem.After booting Ubuntu 19.04, my Lockscreen background is in purple Colour. But after logging in, if I lock the screen the background which I have selected shows correctly.Only after the initial boot up the background I have selected is not showing. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

```
    There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

Selection Path Priority Status 
  * 0 /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css 15 auto mode 
    1 /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css 15 manual mode 
    2 /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css 10 manual mode 
    Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css        10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: I cant right now.  The problem is when i switch on the laptop, the login screen background is purple in color with the Ubuntu logo in the bottom.And then I login into the desktop.After logging in if I lock the screen using the lock icon from the top bar, the image i set for the background appears.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY8sY.jpg

Comment: go through this https://askubuntu.com/q/1086962/739431 and this https://askubuntu.com/q/1135694/739431

Comment: Thank you for your help man. I did it. Also found the following: gdm3=login screen background; gnome-shell=after boot_up background; settings/lockscreen=Sleep background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 19.04 Can't change LockScreen Background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135694/ubuntu-19-04-cant-change-lockscreen-background)