# Ubuntu 19.10 login screen background image

Tags: login-screen, 19.10

Where under "settings" do I find the graphical dialog with which I can change the background of the LOGIN screen from the dull purple solid color to a nice photo of my choosing? Please note, it's okay to just say "it does not exist". Thank you.

Comment: You will have to change the ubuntu.css file content. Search this website for " change login screen background ". It has been answered many times before. Good luck. PS; There is no default GUI for that.

Comment: @PaulCiosek It Does not Exist. There are alternatives to change background of GDM login screen..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1120806/739431 https://askubuntu.com/a/1086968/739431 https://askubuntu.com/a/1135698/739431 https://askubuntu.com/a/1089956/739431