# gdm - login screen background change problem - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: login, themes, gdm

I am trying to change the `noisetexture.png` to black screen but it still flashes a purple screen while logging in .

I changed this

```
#lockDialogGroup {
   background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
   background-repeat: repeat; 
}
```

to

```
#lockDialogGroup {
   background: #00000 url(file:///home/sk/image.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: 6 zeros required.. just change `#2c001e` to `#000000` in the default file.. dont use your own as in question..

Comment: if you dont want black color generated by noisetexture. png.. you need to make lock dialogue content just as `background-color: black; }`