# Making custom gdm theme

Tags: gnome-shell, login-screen, gtk, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-tweak

I want to make my own gdm theme. I know that I can simply edit the ubuntu.css file and try restarting again, but is there better way to do the same ?

I have searched the gnome page for it and i was not able to find resources regarding the same. I am sure that there should be a few tools for that.

Can anyone refer me those tools or links which speaks on it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change login screen background in 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086962/cannot-change-login-screen-background-in-18-10)

Comment: see this from above https://github.com/juhaku/loginized

Comment: @PRATAP thanks but the link you refered refers to a tool which offers an easy way to switch between installed gdm themes , but i want to know the way pf making a gdm theme? Can you help me out?

Comment: your question is very good but i am also in your state.. i too googled about gnome documentation but did not find any guides.. but AFAIK the .css files are making this.. you have already mentioned this in question.. i saw lot of differences in gdm theme by changing the css files.. try installing themes from gnome-look.org and you can realize that .css file makes lot of differences.. if you mean the top bar in gdm login page and left and right indicators etc.. you can dig hardcodes.. but this documentation is available in gnome org or gnome developer..