# Error at Login Screen after changing the background of Login Screen (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: gnome, login-screen, 19.04

My problem happened after I tried to change the background of Login screen.
I have changed the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` and this  `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css`. 
I changed from this one

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background-color: #2C001E; }
```

to this

```
#lockDialogGroup {
   background-image: url(file:///home/rico/Pictures/login/wolf.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center; }
```

However when I reboot, the screen looks like this

[image]

I have changed everything to the default however the error still there. Is there any way to revert the changes or in the worst case, how can i reinstall it?

Comment: @PRATAP do u got the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the previous comments/ chat we had..

It is observed that, your /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css file contents were changed..

to revert back the changes you need /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css file from a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 or Unchanged gnome-shell.css file from running Ubuntu 19.04 file..

Here is the file, https://we.tl/t-BjnNI9u9Si I have just Installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 19.04.

once you download this file.. open it.. copy all the content..

run the below command to open the file

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

Delete all the content in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` and paste the content which you have copied from downloaded file from the above link.

Save the file & Close..

download these two files https://we.tl/t-7Tq96QZy6n and replace `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json` and `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/yaru.json` with these downloaded files.

to check which file is used for alternatives of gdm3.css file..

run `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css` and choose the number belongs to the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css        10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

Now.. your login screen and unlock-screen both will have the default look as it is installed as a fresh Install of Ubuntu 19.04

to change the login-screen background refer to this link..[Cannot change login screen background in 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1086962/739431)

Comment: tks bro, it works perfectly