# Change Ubuntu default color

Tags: 18.04

I installed a Mac OS theme on Ubuntu, all menus are blue, except volume and brightness sliders How can i change them? and how can i change the login screen from purple to an image? Thanks

Comment: hum.. volume and brightness sliders color can be changed by editing your current shell theme..so its hard if you change shell themes frequently.. if you can specify the present shell theme.. its possible to answer your question.. MacOS theme is a shell theme or Icon Theme?

Comment: login background can be changed by this way https://askubuntu.com/a/1086968/739431

Comment: Where did you get the OS theme from?   Some sites provide it with instructions which tell you indirectly how to achieve what you want (though it'll depend where you got it from, gnome-look.org does not though.

Comment: @guiverc i got the theme from here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-ubuntu-look-like-macos/

Comment: @PRATAP thaks, already changed it

Comment: @PRATAP im using the one that came with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

By default in Ubuntu 18.04 the shell theme is the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

to change the required colors.. you need to edit this file..

open the file with below command

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

look for the part

```
/* Slider */
.slider {
  height: 1em;
  -slider-height: 0.3em;
  -slider-background-color: #363633;
  -slider-border-color: #1f1f1c;
  -slider-active-background-color: #dd4814;
  -slider-active-border-color: #bb3e11;
  -slider-border-width: 1px;
  -slider-handle-radius: 6px; }
```

and change the colors as you wish..

for example:

```
/* Slider */
.slider {
  height: 1em;
  -slider-height: 0.3em;
  -slider-background-color: #363633;
  -slider-border-color: #1f1f1c;
  -slider-active-background-color: blue;
  -slider-active-border-color: blue;
  -slider-border-width: 1px;
  -slider-handle-radius: 6px; }
```

[image]

Comment: must i restart to apply changes?

Comment: thanks, it works, does it use hexadecimal colors?