# Is there a command to generate gnome themes?

Tags: gnome, themes

I would like to tweak Gnome theme elements like the background in the lock screen.

I see that one can go and edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` manually for instance. I notice at the top of this file it says:

```
/* This stylesheet is generated, DO NOT EDIT */
```

So it begs the question, generated by what? Is there a tool I can use to customize gnome without manually editing?

Thanks!

Comment: background in the lock screen or login screen also?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1120806/739431

Comment: @PRATAP the linked answer mentions a different file but that still has the same warning as its first line.