# Login loop on 18.10 after attempting to change login screen color

Tags: gnome, login-screen, gnome-shell

I have my Ubuntu 18.10 just installed on my SSD and somehow I broke the desktop.

I was trying to change the login screen color following this forum: [How can I change the purple background color of the lock screen on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981614/how-can-i-change-the-purple-background-color-of-the-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-17-10) and replaced the original `gdm3.css` in `/etc/alternatives/` with its backup after the modification failed. Since then it locked me out. Every time I log in it flashes my wallpaper and crashes/bounces back to the login screen. I tried to reset GNOME settings but it didn't work for me.

But going to console mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (or F2, F3 etc) then type `startx` it loaded the original GNOME desktop just fine.

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Is the backup owned by root? Please run `ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` and post the results!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen to test it i corrupted my gdm3.css file in my Ubuntu 18.10 and rebooted.. its not taking me to desktop..

Comment: `pratap@i7-6550U:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Nov 26 12:22 /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css -> /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css
pratap@i7-6550U:~$`

Comment: So since that file a sym link from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` OP should delete it and create another link to that location

Comment: yes, i tried it in previous and it worked out. but this time, i could not get success. i am trying since morning to see the perfect solution for it. but not able to with my skill level.

Comment: My link is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` why is yours different and am I talking to the OP are you @DemonUnix ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 they introduced Yaru.. if its 18.04 `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` is rite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86228/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-pratap).

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i could manage somehow by `sudo cp -r /media/pratap/108e3c57-a7a6-47c2-8d0e-eae3ea141ce7/usr/share/gnome-shell /usr/share/` where media is my 18.04 and destination is 18.10. it worked.

Comment: Great then there is obviously something wromy with the original copy. Please post that answer as a workaround.