# Grey background overlays GDM3 wallpaper

Tags: gnome, unity, login, desktop-background

i have a weird issue for a while. I have a GDM login screen on Ubuntu 23.04 set via Login Manager Settings, but when launching the system, wallpapers shows for a second and then gets overlayed by grey background. After logging in, the correct wallpaper shows for a second before my dekstop gets loaded. I have this issue for a while now on previous Ubuntu versions also. Previously I've been uploading the background image by some other tools or manually, but the effect was always the same. Currently I'd like to have any other background, but not the grey one :)

Answer (score 0):

Stasiu - It annoys me too - they must have changed something in the sources - all scripts have ubuntu 20.10... or change to lightdm...
probaby we must edit /usr/local/share/themes/default-pure/gnome_shell/gdm.css

[How I can change the GDM login screen wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202129/how-i-can-change-the-gdm-login-screen-wallpaper)

Answer (score 0):

There are two layers right now for Ubuntu 23.04 GDM Login Screen, this is reported as a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2018672.

However, there is a workaround for this. The workaround is to make the top layer transparent using this https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background/blob/main/ubuntu-gdm-set-background-23.04-transparent.

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04.